# Add Marker Points Between Two Specified Location and draw the path in Google map ,Showing Null pointer Exeception

Tags: android

Iam Drawing Path Between Two Specified Locations with Marker.

if Directly Hard Coding the longitude and latitutde values Working fine.

Path and Marker between Two Points Showing Good.

But Getting longitude and latitutde values From Other Intent then Show the Marker Point,Showing Null Pointer Exception.

help me to solve this Issue.(Retriving longitude and latitutde values From Other Intent Working Fine, Showing in Toast Messsage)

```
04-22 15:21:46.268: W/System.err(3561): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 15:21:46.323: D/dalvikvm(3561): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1088K, 20% free 11180K/13943K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
04-22 15:21:46.341: W/System.err(3561):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.bh.<init>(Unknown Source)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fk.a(Unknown Source)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(SourceFile:137)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$a$a.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolyline(Unknown Source)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at com.example.locatiowaypath.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:330)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at com.example.locatiowaypath.MainActivity$ParserTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-22 15:21:46.342: W/System.err(3561):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-22 15:21:46.343: W/System.err(3561):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-22 15:21:46.343: W/System.err(3561):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 15:21:46.343: W/System.err(3561):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-22 15:21:46.344: W/System.err(3561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
04-22 15:21:46.344: W/System.err(3561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 15:21:46.344: W/System.err(3561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 15:21:46.344: W/System.err(3561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
04-22 15:21:46.344: W/System.err(3561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
04-22 15:21:46.348: W/System.err(3561):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

DirectionsJSONParser.java

```
package com.example.locatiowaypath;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;    

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){        
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);                       
                        }                               
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){           
        }


        return routes;
    }   


    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points 
     * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java 
     * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnInfoWindowClickListener{


    public double Latitude1_Current_double,Longitutde1_Current_double,Latitude1_Center_double,Longitude1_Center_double;

     private int zoomLevel = 11;

     LatLng origin1 = new LatLng(Latitude1_Current_double, Longitutde1_Current_double);
        LatLng dest1 = new LatLng(Latitude1_Service_double,Longitude1_Service_double);

        double lat1=Latitude1_Current_double;
        double lang1=Longitutde1_Current_double;
        double lat2=Latitude1_Center_double;
        double lang2=Longitude1_Center_double;


        GoogleMap map;
        ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

         /*private int zoomLevel1 = 14;
         private int zoomLevel2 = 11;*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Latitude1_Current_double = 12.9400834;
        Longitutde1_Current_double = 77.6953668;
        Latitude1_Center_double = 12.971599;
        Longitude1_Center_double = 77.594563;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Direction"+Latitude1_Current_double+","+Longitutde1_Current_double+
                Latitude1_Center_double+","+Longitude1_Center_double,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        // Initializing 
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting reference to Button
    //  Button btnDraw = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_draw);       

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        map = fm.getMap();

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     



         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin1)
                 .title("User Current Location")
                 .snippet("LatLng"+"("+lat1+","+lang1+")")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest1)
                 .title("Service Center Destination Location")
                 .snippet("LatLng"+"("+lat2+","+lang2+")")
                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                  .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));


        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(origin1, zoomLevel));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(dest1, zoomLevel));

        markerPoints.add(origin1);
        markerPoints.add(dest1);


        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin1, dest1);              

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);




        // The map will be cleared on long click
        map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                // Removes all the points from Google Map
                map.clear();

                // Removes all the points in the ArrayList
                markerPoints.clear();

            }
        });




    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;      

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Waypoints
        String waypoints = "";

        for(int i=2;i<markerPoints.size();i++)
        {
            LatLng point  = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(i);
            if(i==2)
            waypoints = "waypoints=";
            waypoints += point.latitude + "," + point.longitude + "|";
        }


        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor+"&"+waypoints;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;


        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            try
            {
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Exceptoin in DownloadTask onPostExecute", "Errroor");
        }

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result)
        {

            try
            {

            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(5);
                lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);              
            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);   

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Exceptoin in  parsing process onPostExecute", "Errroor");
        }

        }           
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("snippet", marker.getSnippet());
        intent.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
        intent.putExtra("position", marker.getPosition());
        startActivity(intent);

    }   
}
```

Comment: At which line you'r getting error?

Comment: i am Getting Error in ParserTask Post execute

Comment: Your `routes` arraylist `null` so you are getting `null pointer exception`.

Comment: i don,t want any arraylist ,I Just Need to plot Path between two Points.

Comment: help me to how to resolve it, Iam the beginner of android.

Comment: Here `List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;`   u didn't initialized your list. So you need to change `List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String, String>>>`

Comment: if replacing ,its showing  Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: Check these links http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/ , http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/route-between-two-locations-with-waypoints-in-google-map-android-api-v2/ , http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 0):

Its possible your map isn't yet initialised. You can guarentee its finished initialising by using:

```
map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        initMap();
    }
});

private void initMap() {
    // Add pins and polylines to map here
}
```

Comment: i Have initialized my map in top,   GoogleMap map;
        ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;